# Sanitize AJAX Response that updates Options in Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have `Bloggers` and `Blogs`.  Each `blog` is associated to a `blogger`.  Here is a picture of the Blog records:

[image: blog records]

Notice that the `title` attribute of Jennell's first `blog` has some javascript that could be triggered if not sanitized properly in certain situations.

Here is exactly one of those situations.  I have two select Boxes:

[image: two select boxes]

For the first select box: the  user picks a `Blogger`.  When this happens:

- an AJAX request gets sent to the server to grab all of the associated `Blogs` for that selected `Blogger`
- the server grabs all the associated `blogs` to that `blogger` and sends them back to the requester
- The response for the ajax request removes all options within the `Blog` select box
- The response for the ajax request then adds in as options in that `Blog` select box all the `blogs` that were grabbed on the server.

The `Blogger` named Jennell has an associated `blog` with a `title` that contains a javascript hack. Thus: when the  Jennell `Blogger` gets selected:

[image: selecting blogger]

That hack within her associated `Blog` will get executed:

[image: javascript executed]

Here is the actual code for the AJAX request:

```
$("body").on('change', '[data-action="blogger_sel"]', function() {
  var blog_sel = $(this).closest('[data-parent-for="blog_sel"]').find('[data-action="blog_sel"]');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/blogs",
    type: "GET",
    data: {blogger_id: $(this).val()},
    success: function (data) {
      blog_sel.children().remove();
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        /* DO NOT APPEND THIS WAY.  VULNERABLE TO USER-ENTERED JAVASCRIPT EXECUTING */
        blog_sel.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
      });
    }
  })
});
```

The issue in the AJAX request is this part:

```
value.title
```

I need to sanitize that.

**Question**:  Within the AJAX response: how can I sanitize `value.title`?

Comment: You should sanitize content before inserting into database and you should never ask this kind of question (to sanitize data client side). Simply, for `title` do not allow tags.

Comment: @skobaljic that is a good point.  This is more of an exercise though.  I guess to make it more realistic: Pretend that we have a huge database that might have some hacks in it.  Moving forward we sanitize attributes of tags, but for whatever reason we cannot sanitize the old data, so we sanitize it client side.

Comment: Your question should be `How to strip tags from string`, for that you already have [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) - below is the jQuery `text()` method. Asking how to sanitize output with Javascript could be confusing, because it almost never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the text/values via attributes, not the html string.

```js
var str = "<script>alert('x');<\/script>Test",
    opt = $("<option></option>", { "text" : str, value : "foo" });
$("select").append(opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It works, but I am not sure *why*  it works.  I guess since you are explicitly setting the option's `text` value it knows to ignore the script tags?  I guess it knows to just add them in the html as text instead of tags?

Comment: because text is text displays the [html entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) so you see the actual characters.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to see a code solution to the question:

```
$("body").on('change', '[data-action="blogger_sel"]', function() {
  var blog_sel = $(this).closest('[data-parent-for="blog_sel"]').find('[data-action="blog_sel"]');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/blogs",
    type: "GET",
    data: {blogger_id: $(this).val()},
    success: function (data) {
      blog_sel.children().remove();
      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        blog_sel.append($('<option>', {
          value: item.id,
          text : item.title
        }));
      });
    }
  })
});
```